# Unable to connect aws documentdb from node.js using mongoose

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, mongoose, aws-documentdb

Here is my node.js code i am trying to connect aws document db using mongoose but getting
below error.

```
const URL = "mongodb://school:SJDJDJDJDD@dev-docdb-2022-09-02-05-55-49.cqsssmioaafcdjkaooj9.ap-south-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/school?ssl=true&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false";

// Connect to MongoDB.
const connect = mongoose.connect(
URL, {
        ssl: true,
        sslValidate: true,
        sslCA: `./rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem`,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    },
{}
);
```

errors i am getting

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-108:~/school_api$ npm start

> graphql-crud@1.0.0 start
> node server.js

 Server ready at http://localhost:4000/graphql
MongooseServerSelectionError: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at Connection.openUri (/home/ubuntu/school_api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:847:32)
    at /home/ubuntu/school_api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:351:10
    at /home/ubuntu/school_api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/home/ubuntu/school_api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/home/ubuntu/school_api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1149:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (/home/ubuntu/school_api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:350:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/school_api/server.js:18:26)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1173:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:838:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:18:47 {
reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map(1) {
    'dev-docdb-2022-09-02-05-55-49.cqioaafcooj9.ap-south-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
}
}
```

I have my cerificate available also inside my code. please take a look.
I am able to connect to mongodb shell from the server. So there must be something wrong
in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const URL = `mongodb://school:SJDJDJDJDD@dev-docdb-2022-09-02-05-55-49.cqsssmioaafcdjkaooj9.ap-south-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/school?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false`

    const addedToUrl = `&tls=true&tlsCAFile=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem`;

    const connect = mongoose.connect(
        `${URL}${addedToUrl}`, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        },
        {}
    );
```

You can place these parameters in the connection string.